# How to put Link from react router dom inside Material UI table

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

Like the title says I need to put Link inside the table from Material UI, but i get these two errors `<td> cannot appear as a child of <a>` `<a> cannot appear as a child of <tr>`. Now obviously I know what these two error messages mean, but I need to put Link as let's say container around cells, because I need to be able to click anywhere inside the row for redirection to another page.

Here is my code:

```
 <TableRow key={index}>
            <Link
              to={`/edit/${apiData.id}/${apiData.name}/${apiData.email}`}
            >
            <TableCell align="left" style={{ paddingLeft: 40 }}>
              {apiData.name}
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">{apiData.email}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">{apiData.status}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">{roles}</TableCell>
            </Link>
            <TableCell align="right" style={{ paddingRight: 40 }}>
              <RoleButton onClick={handleRoleChange}>
                {roles === "Admin" ? "Set as User" : "Set as Admin"}
              </RoleButton>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
```

Anyone know how to fix this, if You do I would greatly appreciate that

Comment: don't wrap `td` or `tr` with `<a>` tag, you can use `onClick` to fire an event and redirect user by a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onClick` in `TableRow`.

```
function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function onRowClick(name) {
    history.push(`/user/${name}`);
  }

  return (
    <Table>
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Age</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        <TableRow onClick={() => onRowClick('tom')}>
          <TableCell>Tom</TableCell>
          <TableCell>26</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  );
}
```